# Верно написание «так же»?

Tags: также

«Я так легка и так же тяжела».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение без контекста не имеет смысла в обоих вариантах.
**Я так легка и так же (= таким же образом, как легка) тяжела** — бессмыслица.
**Я так легка и также (= тоже) тяжела** — бессмыслица.

Предположу, что тут имеется в виду **Я так легка и [одновременно] так же (= так же, как раньше) тяжела** — в таком виде имеется хоть какой-то смысл.

Comment: Я так легка и так же тяжела,
Как мысли, что покоя не дают
Раздельно!

Comment: @flossyU ну так задавайте вопрос с контекстом. Штатные экстрасенсы сайта в отпуске :)

Comment: Да. Я потом увидала продолжение...